# Bootstrap Table Width Issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem regarding the width in a bootstrap table, it goes way to the side of the website, screenshot under

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLZwD.png

EDIT:

```
<div class="container">
                <h1>URL Stats <small>Shortened URL's with their full stats.</small></h1>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="statstable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>URL ID</th><th>URL Unique ID</th><th>Short Link</th><th>Redirect Link</th><th>Date Created</th><th>End Date</th><th>Days Left</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <hr>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE shortlinkid='$shortlinkid'") or die(mysql_error());
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            $now = date("Y-m-d");
                            $start = $row['date_created'];
                            $end = $row['end_date'];
                            $diff = (strtotime($end) - strtotime($now))/24/3600; 
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['shortlinkid']."</td>";
                            echo "<td><a href='http://".$row['fullurl']."'>".$row['fullurl']."</a></td>";
                            echo "<td><a href='".$row['redirect']."'>".$row['redirect']."</a></td>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['date_created']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['end_date']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$diff."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
```

This has not been an issue before, and it works fine in other browsers other than Chrome

Comment: Include some code, please.

Comment: Could you include the generated HTML rather than the PHP?

Comment: Can you consolidate those long links? They might be pushing the column wider.

Comment: How do I do this @Joe? I'm new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
echo "<td><a href='http://".$row['fullurl']."'>".$row['fullurl']."</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='".$row['redirect']."'>".$row['redirect']."</a></td>";
```

To this:

```
echo "<td><a href='http://".$row['fullurl']."'>Full URL</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='".$row['redirect']."'>Redirect</a></td>";
```

Instead of echoing the entire URL for the link label, use some descriptive text to click on. Change labels as needed.